# PHP echo() MySQL result containing <> characters?

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

I am retrieving data from my SQL database...

data exactly as it is in the DB = `(21:48:26) <username> some text here. is it ok?`

when i try and `echo $row['log']."<br>";`

it displays it as = (21:48:26) some text here. is it ok?

i assume this is due to the <> brackets making it think its an HTML opener... would this be the case? and if so how would one echo a string that contains HTML?

Comment: ? I don't understand your problem. Is it not echoing what's in the db.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko He ran into the same problem when asking the question here on SO: he didn't escape the `<` and `>` characters

Comment: I thought that may be the case but I don't have enough rep yet to edit entrys to see.

Comment: yes sorry :| i seem to have a habit of forgetting the formatting, and that just proves and my question had the same problem as my "question" lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to translate HTML control characters into their entities:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($row['log'])."<br>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the characters so it is not recognized as an HTML element, but as text:

```
echo htmlentities( $row['log'] ) . '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

> i assume this is due to the <>
>   brackets making it think its an HTML
>   opener...

Yes, any construction in <> brackets is treated by web browser as HTML tag. So, you should use either htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities() or some similar custom function to convert "<" and ">" symbols to "&lt;" and "&gt;" strings, which are displayed to user as brackets.

Some more comments:

- ALL text data displayed to user must be passed through htmlspecialchars() funciton  (or through other function with similar behavior), since "some text" may also contain tags, etc.
- Probably it would be better to store date/time, username and "some text" in separate table columns in DB, in order to satisfy relational database constraints. This may require some additional input data parsing.